# Java persistence API: Glassfish tries to use derby instead of MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, glassfish, derby

I wrote the following **persistence.xml** for a **glassfish** webapp:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
    version="2.1">

   <persistence-unit name="mypu" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
     <description>my</description>
     <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
     <class>my.OntClass</class>

     <properties>

       <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/user_lindenb"/>
       <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="appuser"/>
       <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="apppassword"/>
       <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
       <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="false"/><!--  http://java.dzone.com/articles/jpa-performance-optimization -->
        <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="MySQL"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="ALL"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="false"/>
     </properties>
   </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

The MySQL server is running and I can connect to the MySQL server from a servlet using a:

```
@Resource (name="jdbc/MysqlDS" )
javax.sql.DataSource mysqlDS;
```

Now, I want to use the persistence API. But when I want to deploy my application it raises the following error:

```
remote failure: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while preparing the app : Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused.
```

As far as I understand, it tries to connect to Derby instead of MySQL?

```
glassfish log:
(...) 
Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.DisconnectException: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused.
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetAgent.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.newAgent_(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.initConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection40.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.ClientJDBCObjectFactoryImpl40.newNetConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDataSource.getConnectionX(Unknown Source)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
    at javax.net.DefaultSocketFactory.createSocket(SocketFactory.java:271)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.OpenSocketAction.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    ... 79 more
(...)
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Go to the Glassfish admin console, and remove any old web apps. For directories: clean them up too. How exactly I hope someone else can tell you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replaced

```
 <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
```

by

```
 <jta-data-source>jdbc/MysqlDS</jta-data-source>
```

seems to work now...